# How to pass multiple functions from class component to a functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react, and my goal is pass pass a function from a class component to execute inside a class component on a button click. Code breakdown as bellow.

Class component class as bellow

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Dimensions,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import Header from './src/components/Header';
import { Drawer } from 'native-base';

export default class App extends Component {
  closeDrawer=()=> {
   this._drawer._root.close()
  };
 openDrawer=()=> {
   this._drawer._root.open()
 };


  render() {
    return (
      <Drawer
        openDrawerOffset={100}
        styles={drawerStyles}
        ref={(ref) => { this._drawer = ref; }}
        content={<SideBar navigator={this._navigator} />}
        onClose={() => this.closeDrawer()} >
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }} >

          <View>
            <Header openDrawerClicked={this.openDrawer} />
          </View>

        </View>
      </Drawer>
    );
  }
}
```

I need to pass the "openDrawer" function first to Header component, and then inside that I have a button configured in a separate child component where the button click is configured.Code as bellow

Header component

```
const Header = (props) => {

    return (

                <View style={styles.menuViewStyle}>
                    <Button imagePath={'menuIcon'}/>
                </View>
    );
};
```

Button component where i need the function to be execute and toggle open and close functions.

```
const assets = require('./assets')

const ButtonWithImage = (props) => {
    const { buttonStyle } = styles;
    const clickEvent = () => {
        // Button click event
    }

    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={clickEvent} style={buttonStyle}>
            <Image
                source={assets[props.imagePath]}
                style={styles.ImageIconStyle}
            />
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
export default class App extends Component {
  openDrawer=()=> { //bind lexical scope using arrow synax
    this._drawer._root.open()
  };

  render() {
    return (
      //....
          <View>
            <Header openDrawerClicked={this.openDrawer} />
          </View>
    );
  }
}
```

In Header :

```
const Header = ({openDrawerClicked}) => {  // get `openDrawerClicked`

    return (
   //passed `openDrawerClicked` for Button component
                <View style={styles.menuViewStyle}>
                    <Button openDrawer= {openDrawerClicked} imagePath={'menuIcon'}/>
                </View>
    );
};
```

In Button :

```
const ButtonWithImage = (props) => {
    const clickEvent = () => {
        props.openDrawer();
    }

    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.clickEvent} style={buttonStyle}>
            //...
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
};
```

Comment: What would i do if i wants to pass multiple functions from parent class to header and then to button click ??

Comment: you have to do in the same way mentioned above

Comment: is there a way to toggle open and close functions sir, cuz i passed them but the toggle isnt working

Comment: I think its something to do with 

 <Drawer
        openDrawerOffset={100}
        styles={drawerStyles}
        ref={(ref) => { this._drawer = ref; }}
        content={<SideBar navigator={this._navigator} />}
        onClose={() => this.closeDrawer()} >

Opening the drawe works, but clicking the same button it wont close, thats my issue

Answer (score 1):

For that first you need to pass the function from Header component to Button component, like this:

```
<Button imagePath={'menuIcon'} openDrawerClicked={props.openDrawerClicked} />
```

Then inside the button component call that method, like this:

```
const clickEvent = () => {
    props.openDrawerClicked();
}
```

**Suggestion:**

To avoid confusion better to use same name at all the place either `openDrawerClicked` or `openDrawer`, otherwise in parent component, function name will be `openDrawer` and inside child name will be `openDrawerClicked`.